# ENS setResolver bad jump destination

Tags: ens

When i use the Ens - Registry Contract to setResolver(), I am getting a bad jump destination.

I am the using the proper namehash of my newly won domain and the "0x1da022710df5002339274aadee8d58218e9d6ab5" proper ENS resolver addr for the resolver address.

I have tried this with 2, 20, and 40 Gwei, same problem every time.

Comment: Paying more for gas or with more wouldn't change anything. Do you have any transaction IDs of failed attempts?

Comment: [First attempt](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e37ca87251de4a0bbbe1ecbabc0950d6a948af2e02acf0caf453101be894357)

[Second attempt](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x800771df1163e118539c0e7d2afde73b2f901531908b4df197ebf11d54da738b)

Comment: It looks to me that the node of which you're trying to set the resolver (0x7a7bc2c...) isn't actually registered. Are you sure you're doing the namehash properly?