# ENS testnet contract - bad jump when following quickstart tutorial

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, ens, bad-jump

Following the [quickstart guidance](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/quickstart.html) using Ropsten testnet, I have done the following on a synced geth console:

```
> loadScript('/my/path/to/ensutils-testnet.js');
> new Date(testRegistrar.expiryTimes(web3.sha3('blipblop.test')).toNumber() * 1000)

<Date Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 BST>

> ens.setResolver(namehash('blipblop.test'), publicResolver.address, {from: eth.accounts[0]});

"0x28f01d23b98a7b4fe1bc4324cb70e406714e1c14e64e632708f8ec44cebbde78"
```

When I look up the [transaction on etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x28f01d23b98a7b4fe1bc4324cb70e406714e1c14e64e632708f8ec44cebbde78), it reports a bad jump destination and the name does no resolve:

```
> getAddr('blipblop.test')

"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Should there be a delay between setting the resolver and being able to resolve the name?

Related (on main net): [ENS setResolver bad jump destination](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16830/ens-setresolver-bad-jump-destination)

Comment: You have not provided full code so it is not clear what you are doing. From what I can see there are errors e.g web3.sha3('blipblop.test') instead of web3.sha3('blipblop')

Comment: @ThomasClowes thanks - I've edited to includ `loadscript` command. I don't have any further code to add - is there something obvious missing? I've followed the linked guide --> http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @ThomasClowes Thanks I've managed to get it working now - I think I had missed the `testRegistrar` step

Comment: @atomh33ls this can be tied off neatly, if you write and accept your own answer

Comment: @carver I was a bit hasty above - whilst the contract bad jump error no longer occurs, the `getAddr('blipblop.test')` still gives `"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`

Comment: After setting the resolver to the public resolver, did you also call `resolver.setAddr()`?

Comment: @carver thanks, no, have done it [now](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd64dc2d6b01a18169bd56dad87747c012a2edf14dee8b8fb7c0aace0aa9dfd14). I still get `0x00...`  after `getAddr` however

Comment: How did you generate the namehash value `0x27d224a842cd4d6f0e5161a3dbe482a65e8848ad4bbc8645faacaf989157b97b`? I get namehash: `> namehash('blipblop.test')
"0x370f76c0ca0ed4644977abd7995b060f3f13dca45a330b2cd9ef9275b009da0b"`

Comment: @carver Ah yes I repeated with `blipblop2.test` !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63951/discussion-between-carver-and-atomh33ls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the series of steps that worked (after jumping in chat with @atomh33ls).

```
> loadScript('/my/path/to/ensutils-testnet.js');

> testRegistrar.register(web3.sha3('blipblop'), eth.accounts[0],
                             {from: eth.accounts[0]});
// wait for block inclusion...

> ens.setResolver(namehash('blipblop.test'), publicResolver.address,
                             {from: eth.accounts[0]});

> publicResolver.setAddr(namehash('blipblop.test'), publicResolver.address,
                             {from: eth.accounts[0]});
// wait for block inclusion...

> getAddr('blipblop.test')
0x8058596db747ca76e2e769be88fb07cea5a47f89
```